# Flask Database Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am using this tutorial as a guideline. http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

I want to have Categories that can heave multiple Products. Similar to how he has a User with multiple Posts.

when I open up the python interpreter and try to create a category

```
>>>from app import db, models
>>>u = models.Category(name="Test")
```

I get this error

```
/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py", line 1387, in _generate_backref
self, mapper))
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'category' on relationship 'Category.products': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Product|product'
```

So there is a problem with the backref. In the tutorial (and I have tried it with his code) he is able to make a User with similar syntax.

I even tried using all of his files and created and migrated a new database and I get the same error.

Here is my models.py file:

```
from app import db

WR_IP_NO = 0
WR_IP_YES = 1

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    products = db.relationship('Product', backref = 'category', lazy = 'dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category %r>' % (self.name)

class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    courseName = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    ip = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = WR_IP_YES)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
    productRev = db.Column(db.String(64))
    #use when database is updated?
    releaseDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category> %r>' % (self.courseName)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's because you've got a collision.  The error is:

```
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'category' on relationship 'Category.products': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Product|product'`
```

You can see that you've created a relationship within `Category` to `Product` which is two way, so you could do `category.products` to list all the products associated with that category, or alternatively you could go `product.category` which would give you the category for the selected product.

But you've already got a `category` property in `Product`.  So just change it to be unique-- your `Product` class should generally look like:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.String(64), db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    courseName = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
    ip = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default = WR_IP_YES)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer)
    productRev = db.Column(db.String(64))
    #use when database is updated?
    releaseDate = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Category> %r>' % (self.courseName)
```

See how I've changed `category` to `category_id` so that the backref no longer collides with it.

Comment: Does this enforce renaming the SQL database field category to category_id?